# Console says typeof variable is object, but is somehow undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined, javascript-objects

I'm trying to take an object and extract some contents into a new variable, but I'm running into undefined variable issues. Below is my code:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
<script>

var rows = [];
function start() {

  // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
  gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': 'AIzaSyDrnDZyBpObyAOWaZuqzq1DUEZBJNzAu-8',
    // clientId and scope are optional if auth is not required.
    'clientId': '743372987679-n3a809hjko7gegvf4g4d5q8gdfs052oq.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'scope': 'profile',
  }).then(function() {
      return gapi.client.request({
      'path': 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1KsEEqEIaCzLXmGmUX2kQfJ6oW3k2n2-mc0dCiq7GzTU/values/Sheet3'
      });
    }).then(function(response){
      rows = response;
      onResultsSuccess(response);
  });
};
// 1. Load the JavaScript client library.
gapi.load('client', start);

var test = rows['result']['values'];
```

In the console, my `rows` object looks normal:

[image]

But whenever I run my script, I receive errors:

[image]

[image]

I've browsed other topics but can't seem to find what is going wrong in my instance.

Comment: Trying to use the result of an asynchronous function call before its callback? By the time you type `rows` into the console the results have come back.

Comment: At the moment you are trying to access `rows`, the graphql response hasn't been received yet.